# Writing out a large amount of records to flat files returned via a Stored Procedure in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to retrieve approximately 1 million records from a SQL Server database and write these records out to numerous flat files (each file will contain say 100,000 records)

What I plan to do is the following:

- Call a stored procedure that returns the first 100,000 records (only records that aren't flagged as processed)
- Iterate through each of these records and write it out to the flat file
- Call another stored procedure that then updates a status field to flag that the record has been processed.

Do you think this is the most efficient way of writing this and how do I go about setting up a loop to ensure that all million or so records are processed.

Comment: Indeed this is the most efficient way to write it because you already know how to do that... Or you have some other criteria in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks OK, except the second point. You need not to iterate through each record. You can use **bcp** utility to write the output of stored procedure directly to the file. Have a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility .

See similar discussion https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/546777/HowplusToplusExportplusDataplusToplustheplus-csvpl . Solution 6 has pretty neat approach.